# XLAT table ignoring certain characters

Tags: assembly, lookup

I want to use XLAT to covert characters, however there are certain characters that I would like to ignore. I am new to assembly, so some of this may not be needed.

```
    .data
        chars db 65 dup (' ')           ;the 65 characters below 'A'
        db 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ;A-Z in uppercase
        db  6 dup(' ')                  ;characters 91-96
        db 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' ;a-z in lowercase
        db  133 dup(' ')                ;remaining characters
```

If I enter the string of characters "abc..xyz". it will appear correctly as "ABC..XYZ". However, any special characters appear as spaces, which makes sense, because that is what I have in my code. My goal is to have nothing written to output when one of these characters are processed. What should I have written instead of db 133 dup(' ')?

Comment: You have to either explicitly check that either the input character isn't supposed to be outputted or that converted character isn't supposed to be outputted.

Comment: For the character values you don't want translated, just set the value to the index, so [0] == 0, [1] == 1, [64] = 64, ... . This way the value before and after XLAT remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmp al,20h
 je loop #continue loop
 #print logic here
```

But you could do it without xlat. 
Below pseudo code to be implemented

```
if (  x>='a' && x<='z') print (x-32) //(x and (not 32))
else if (x>='A' && x<='Z') print(x)
```